# Define a variable and input at the same time?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, for-loop, whiptail

Excuse the confusing question. I'm not sure exactly how to phrase it?

I need to define a variable:

```
variable = "Description$count"
```

While at the same time using it as an input.. if that makes any sense?:
`--inputbox "$(Description$count)`

```
for ((count=$(ovftool vco.ovf | grep -i -A 60 Properties: | grep Description: | wc -l); count > -1; count--))
do

        declare "DiagRes$Count"=$(whiptail --inputbox "$(Description$count)" 8 110 --title "$Label1" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
done
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Could you clarify it a little bit? In what way do you want to "use it as an input"? Could you write a very short example, without the rest of surrounding code, of what you expect the variable to start out as, and what you expect to end up with?

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you for your attention and I'm sorry for the ambiguous question. 
So for example lets say $count has a value of 1 
I want the --inputbox of whiptail to use $description1 which has already been assigned a vaulue earlier in the script
Then $count will increase to 2 and --inputbox of whiptail will use $description2 and so on
Does that make sense? I know am probably making it harder than it has to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to build up variable names as something like `"\$description$count"`, this seems like a good place to use [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays).

Just define your array elements as follows:

```
description[0]="First description"
description[1]="Second description"
```

And then in your loop, assign your results in an array, and extract your descriptions from the first array:

```
diag_res[$i]=$(whiptail --inputbox "${description[$i]}" ...)
```

Note that arrays are a Bash-specific feature, and aren't supported by all POSIX shells.